# When using the index settings with auto_expand_replicas set to "0-all," an issue arises where primary shards are concentrated on specific nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

Due to the service requirements, the setting "auto_expand_replicas" is configured as "0-all," enabling replica shards to be present on all nodes. However, there is an issue where primary shards are concentrated on a specific node, which can negatively impact performance.
[image]

To address this, the following steps are being utilized, and we want to know if there are any potential risks and if there is a better approach:

Step 1: Set "auto_expand_replicas" to false and "number_of_replicas" to 0.
[image]
Step 2: Verify that primary shards are evenly distributed across all nodes.
[image]
Step 3: Set "auto_expand_replicas" back to "0-all."
[image]
Step 4: finish

Please let us know if there are any potential risks involved in these steps, and if there are any better alternatives.

I proceeded as in the text.